# jQuery find all buttons and click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a snippet of javascript that Renders individual buttons for Files which I add to Upload them individually as below

```
data.context = $('<button name=uploadFile/>').text('Start Individual Upload')
    .appendTo(document.body)
                .click(function () {
                    // code to do individual upload (removed for brevity)
                });
```

Rendered markup if I have selected 3 files for example will look like:

```
<button name="uploadFile">Start Upload</button>
<button name="uploadFile">Start Upload</button>
<button name="uploadFile">Start Upload</button>
```

And if I click each button idividually the click handler will be called and the file will upload.

What I want to try and have now is a Upload all button which I can add to my html and then a click handler function on that upload all button which trigger the click handler for each individual upload button (i.e. - mimicking the user clicking each Start Upload Button?

```
 <input id="uploadAllFiles" type="button">

$('#uploadAllFiles').on("click", function () {
    // not sure what to do here to find all buttons with name = uploadFile and trigger clicking     them
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click the uploadAllFiles button, click each of the buttons with the name uploadFile

```
$('#uploadAllFiles').on("click", function() {
    //This will click each of the buttons with the
    //attribute name set to "uploadFile"
    $('button[name="uploadFile"]').click()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, at the risk of getting shot down for answering *not* the question, but the underlying motivation...

I would not do it that way. The button click handler is just a UI interface, quasi-controller, to launch business logic, which is uploading files. Instead, I would isolate the logic into sepaarte functions, and have each click handler invoke its function, and the upload-all invoke them all.

Sort of like this:

```
data.context = $('<button name=uploadFile/>').text('Start Individual Upload')
.appendTo(document.body)
            .click(createClickHandler(fileName)); // assuming filename is the name of the file to upload
```

Where `createClickHandler` is:

```
var allfiles = [];
var createClickHandler = function(filename) {
  var fileupload = function() {
    // upload file logic referencing "filename" var
  }, handler = function() {
   // click handler logic
   fileupload();
  };
  allfiles.push(fileupload);
  return(handler);
};
```

And now when someone clicks the load all:

```
.click(function() {
   $.each(allfiles,function(f) {
     f();
   });
});
```

Comment: can you edit your answer to include the create click handler function formatted as code?

Comment: Drat, I thought I did. All it takes is one missed whitespace. I do so wish they had github style formatting on SO.